# Presta Shop issue with paying my Paypal

Tags: paypal, prestashop

This week we now have an issue with our prestaship website. When we go to check out, it will not transfer us across to paypal at the appropriate time. We receive the following message:

Error occurred:

Please try to contact the merchant:

```
<b>PayPal response:</b>
->
```

Please help since Paypal is our only method of payment so this is a big issue for us.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is because of the Bug in SSL 3.0. Older prestashop modules are affected, the tricky part is, that the paypal module does not show any update in the backend.

You have to download the newest module version on the addons from paypal.

http://addons.prestashop.com/en/payments-gateways-prestashop-modules/1748-paypal.html

The SSL 3.0 support was initially planned for december the 3rd, but I believe it was delayed until 12.1.